# ORO CRM: Could not find bundle resource in config.yml

Tags: orocrm, orocommerce

I am trying to install ORO CRM from scratch after adding an AppBundle.

`bin/console oro:install --env=prod`

The following errors occur:

> In FileLoader.php line 168:
>
> [Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException]   The
>   file "@AppBundle/Resources/config/config.yml" does not exist (in:
>   /home/project/src/config) in @AppBundle/Resources/config/config.yml
>   (which is being imported from "/home/project/src/config/config.yml"). 
>   Make sure the "AppBundle" bundle is correctly registered and loaded in
>   the application kernel class. If the bundle is registered, make sure
>   the bundle path "@AppBundle/Resources/config/config.yml" is not empty.
>
> In FileLocator.php line 71:
>
> [Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLocatorFileNotFoundException] 
>   The file "@AppBundle/Resources/config/config.yml" does not exist (in:
>   /home/project/src/config).

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR

remove the `@AppBundle/Resources/config/config.yml` import from `config/config.yml` and add the configuration to the following location in your bundle `src/AppBundle/Resources/config/oro/app.yml`.

Background

Apparently, there is an additional `OroRequirements` checker which has its own `YamlFileLoader`. The loader does not know how to interpret bundle resource starting with @ and fails. It makes sense since oro looks for app configuration in the bundle itself at `Resources/config/oro/app.yml` but the error message should be more clear or bundle imports could be simply ignored.